# formatSelection of Flutter Quill is reset when user write content in Korean

Tags: flutter, quill, rich-text-editor

My issue is about [Mobile]

Font size changes work well for English text. However, if user enter Korean, the font size is reset. For example, if user change the font size to 19 and type "하", the "ㅎ" is entered in size 19, but the moment user press "ㅏ", the "하" is changed to size 15.

```
final Map<int, String> unSelectedFontSizeAssets = {
   11: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_11_default.svg",
   13: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_13_default.svg",
   15: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_15_default.svg",
   19: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_19_default.svg",
   24: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_24_default.svg",
   28: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_28_default.svg",
   30: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_30_default.svg",
   34: "assets/svgs/icon_webeditor_txtsize_34_default.svg",
 };

...unSelectedFontSizeAssets.entries.map((entry) {
                           return QuillIconButton(
                             hoverElevation: 0,
                             highlightElevation: 0,
                             size: 24,
                             onPressed: () {
                               widget._quillController.formatSelection(
                                   Attribute.fromKeyValue(
                                       'size', getFontSize(entry.key.sp)));
                               setState(() {
                                 _selectedFontSize = entry.key;
                               });
                             },
                             icon: _selectedFontSize == entry.key
                                 ? SvgPicture.asset(selectedFontSizeAssets[
                                     _selectedFontSize]!)
                                 : SvgPicture.asset(entry.value),
                           );
                         }).toList(),

 dynamic getFontSize(dynamic sizeValue) {
   if (sizeValue is String && ['small', 'large', 'huge'].contains(sizeValue)) {
     return sizeValue;
   }

   if (sizeValue is double) {
     return sizeValue;
   }

   if (sizeValue is int) {
     return sizeValue.toDouble();
   }

   assert(sizeValue is String);
   final fontSize = double.tryParse(sizeValue);
   if (fontSize == null) {
     throw 'Invalid size $sizeValue';
   }
   return fontSize;
 }
```

[refer to below video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/103037733/249352910-2dcd338d-c84f-4f7b-b4d7-45d6e1bfddab.gif)